# Prove that $R$ is an equivalence on $\mathscr P(A)$. Is this correct?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

Suppose $B\subseteq A$, and define a relation R on $\mathscr{P}(A)$ as follows:

$$R=\{(X,Y)\in\mathscr{P}(A) \times \mathscr{P}(A)\mid(X\mathrel{\triangle} Y)\subseteq B\}$$

Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathscr{P}(A)$.

Ok so here's how I did the reflexive part. I want to know if it is correct and whether I have the right idea.

Let X be an arbitrary set on $\mathscr{P}(A)$. Also, let $y\in(X\mathrel{\triangle} X)$. This means $$y\in(X\setminus X)\cup(X\setminus X)\;,$$ so $y\in\emptyset$. Since $\emptyset\in B$ and since $y$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $(X \mathrel{\triangle} X)\subseteq B$. Since $X$ was arbitrary we have shown that $(X,X)\in R$. So $R$ is reflexive on $\mathscr{P}(A)$, as desired.

Update:

There's another part to this question,

Prove that for every X $\in\mathscr{P}(A)$ there is exactly one Y $\in$ [X]$_R$ such that Y $\cap$ B = $\emptyset$.

I believe I got the existence part of the proof but I don't know how to complete the uniqueness part.

My proof: (Goal: $\forall X \in \mathscr{P}(A) \exists ! Y \in$ [X]$_R$(Y $\cap B = \emptyset$ )

Let X be arbitrary set of $\mathscr{P}(A)$

**Existence**:

Let Y=$\emptyset$. So, LHS = Y$\cap$B = $\emptyset \cap$B = $\emptyset$ = RHS, as desired.

**Uniqueness:**

Let W and Z be arbitrary sets in [X]$_R$ such that W$\cap$B=$\emptyset$ and Z$\cap$B=$\emptyset$.

(I know my uniqueness goal is to prove X=Z but I don't know how to go about it)

Comment: Ah, but the empty set doesn't contain any elements - this means that it is not possible for you to let $y\in X\Delta X$. No such $y$ exists.

Comment: It's really hard to edit when you do things line `(X$\Delta$X)$\subseteq$ B`. Much easier to write `$(X\Delta X)\subseteq B$`.

Comment: @HowDoIMath: That is not a problem. The argument shows that *if* $y\in X\mathrel{\triangle}X$, *then* $y\in\varnothing$, and hence there is no such $y$, i.e., $X\mathrel{\triangle}X=\varnothing$. It’s an unnecessarily roundabout way to show that $X\mathrel{\triangle}X=\varnothing$, but it’s not incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. It’s not true, however, that $\varnothing\in B$: you mean that $\varnothing\subseteq B$. You could also make the argument a bit clearer. There’s no reason to look at $y\in X\mathrel{\triangle}X$: just observe that

$$X\mathrel{\triangle}X=(X\setminus X)\cup(X\setminus X)=\varnothing\subseteq B\;,$$

so that $(X,X)\in R$, as desired.

I think that you’ll find it even more straightforward to verify that $R$ is symmetric. The hardest part will be verifying transitivity of $R$, which amounts to showing that if $X,Y,Z\subseteq A$, $X\mathrel{\triangle}Y\subseteq B$, and $Y\mathrel{\triangle}Z\subseteq B$, then $X\mathrel{\triangle}Z\subseteq B$. HINT: Calculate

$$(X\mathrel{\triangle}Y)\mathrel{\triangle}(Y\mathrel{\triangle}Z)\;.$$

Comment: I know that $(X\Delta Y)\(Y\Delta Z)\cup(Y\Delta Z)\(X\Delta Y)$.I don't know what you want me to get to with the hint for trasitivity.

Comment: @MathHelpNeeded: The operation of symmetric difference is associative and commutative, so $$(X\mathrel{\triangle}Y)\mathrel{\triangle}(Y\mathrel{\triangle}Z)=(X \mathrel{\triangle}Z) \mathrel{\triangle} (Y\mathrel{\triangle}Y)\;.$$ Now simplify.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be $\emptyset$? I don't see the point. Is it that $\emptyset \subseteq$ B. So $X\mathrel{\triangle}Z\subseteq B$. Can I make this conclusion?

Comment: @MathHelpNeeded: the point is that $Y\mathrel{\triangle}Y=\varnothing$, so the original expression is equal to $(X\mathrel{\triangle}Z)\mathrel{\triangle}\varnothing$, which is equal to $X\mathrel{\triangle}Z$. Thus, $X\mathrel{\triangle}Z$ is equal to the symmetric difference of two subsets of $B$. Therefore, ...

Comment: I know the goal is to show X$\Delta$Z$\subseteq$B but how do I know that the symmetric difference of two subsets of B is in B? Is this intuitive?

Comment: @MathHelpNeeded: I think that it’s fairly intuitive if you understand symmetric difference, but it’s easy to prove that if $S\subseteq B$ and $T\subseteq B$, then $S\mathrel{\triangle}T\subseteq B$ from either of the usual definitions of $S\mathrel{\triangle}T$ (as $(S\setminus T)\cup(T\setminus S)$ or as $(S\cup T)\setminus(S\cap T)$).